# What is the purpose of def get_instances_from_related() method in django_elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am working on creating elastic search indexing for the python Django project for a model with related tables.

When I am working on it I came across the website https://pypi.org/project/django-elasticsearch-dsl/6.4.2/. I have followed the steps and implemented an elastic search for my model and it's working fine.

But I can't find the purpose of the method def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance).
Why we are using this method, where and when we are it is called.

Could anyone please explain this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose you have this `Document`:

```
class ChildDocument(Document):

    parent = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        ...
    })

    class Index:
        name = 'children'
        settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                    'number_of_replicas': 0}

    class Django:
        model = Child
        related_models = [Parent]
        queryset_pagination = 5000


        fields = [
        ...
        ]

    def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
        if isinstance(related_instance, Parent):
            return Child.objects.filter(parent=related_instance)
```

`get_instances_from_related()` is used when one of the `related_models` changes (in our case a `Parent` object). `django_elasticsearch_dsl` needs a list of all the `Child` objects which reference the `parent` object so it can update the `parent` field of each `child` in the index.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in docs, get_instances_from_related() is a method, that you define to fetch all of instances of a `Document.Django.model`, that are linked to `related_instance` in some way (like ForeignKey, ManyToMany).

It's pretty neat, since it can support multiple related models. You just need to specity a way to get `QuerySet` of a main model through related_model and pass related instance as a parameter.